# Scale layout items equally on large screens

Tags: android, xml, layout

I've got a 4-item start screen in my app, which looks like the following:
[image]

What's important to me there:
- All items do have the same width (not regarding how much text is actually in it)
- Look the same on all devices (small-screen, mdpi, large-screen, etc.)

Im just wondering if there is a easy solution about this problem?

I've tried using 3 LinearLayouts but thats really awkward..
(1 presenting the layout root[vertical] and two which do each contain 2 buttons[horizonal]).
Making this layout ready for multiple screens would require a lot of fixed-width and fixed-margin hacking. Just like "button margin = 30dp on xlarge, 20 on large, 15 on normal,...".

My layout-xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"     
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:id="@+id/main_root"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center" >

<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_learn"
                android:text="@string/mainBtn_learn" 
                style="@style/mainBtn"
                android:onClick="handleBtnClick"
                android:layout_margin="20dip" />

    <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_quiz"
                android:text="@string/mainBtn_quiz" 
                style="@style/mainBtn"
                android:onClick="handleBtnClick" 
                android:layout_margin="20dip"  />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_search"
                android:text="@string/mainBtn_search" 
                style="@style/mainBtn"
                android:onClick="handleBtnClick" 
                android:layout_margin="20dip" />

    <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_more"
                android:text="@string/mainBtn_more" 
                style="@style/mainBtn"
                android:onClick="handleBtnClick"
                android:layout_margin="20dip"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a view which "auto-scales" these Buttons or still any other easier solution?

## Edit:

So, in special, you need something like
button:

```
 android:layout_width="15%" // 15% of screen width / height depending on the orientation
 android:layout_marginBottom="10%" // see above
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty new to Android development but I can show you what worked for me in a similar case. I defined my layout as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/outputText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:editable="false" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/outputSpinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:prompt="@string/OutputBaseOptionsPrompt" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have a horizontal layout with two items. The LinearLayout has a width of "match_parent" so that it is as wide as the screen. Both items in the layout have the following:

```
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
```

Since both items have a layout_weight of 1, they will be drawn at the same width. In this case, each item takes up half of the available space. If you change the weight of one of these items to "2" then it will be twice as wide as the item with a weight of "1".

Comment: Why did you give your childs a layout_width of 0dp instead of fill_parent/match_parent?

Comment: As I said, I am very new to Android development. I was trying a number of things to get the layout to look right. I don't know if I read this somewhere or if I just happened to try it. I just changed to fill_parent and I still get the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Do you already have xml that makes it work on one screen size? If so post what you have so far.

I would suggest using a RelativeLayout for your root though. You can use the alignCenter attributes to float your children towards the middle. Then you just have to hard code the inner margins (how far apart you want the buttons) rather than the margin from yourself to the wall.

You could also avoid having to hard code the inner margin by making your own button 9 patch images. You can just add a border of transparent pixels in your image to represent the margin. You'll probably still want to supply an image for each density you wish to support though.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I can't/don't want to use 9-patch-images - the button drawables are android shapes :/. Either, it seems like a bad hack doing so. I like the margin idea, that's what im basically doing. I've added the code above, take a look on it!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is you dont use hardcoded values any where
Put three images with same name in hdpi mdpi and ldpi folders in drawables

an run the code